# How can I purge recently deleted objects?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, linked-data

```
import bpy


selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects

for obj in selected_objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
    for block in bpy.data.meshes:
        if block.users == 0:
            bpy.data.meshes.remove(block)
```

I need purge only removed mesh objects and leave the rest of the garbage untouched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Batch remove.**

In latter versions there is the ability to batch remove a number of ID objects in one fell swoop.

```
>>> D.batch_remove(
batch_remove(ids=(id1, id2, ...)
.. method:: batch_remove(ids=(id1, id2, ...))
Remove (delete) several IDs at once.
WARNING: Considered experimental feature currently.
Note that this function is quicker than individual calls to :func:`remove()` (from :class:`bpy.types.BlendData`
ID collections), but less safe/versatile (it can break Blender, e.g. by removing all scenes...).
:arg ids: Iterables of IDs (types can be mixed).
:type subset: sequence
```

Test script, remove the selected objects, then remove any orphaned linked data they  left behind.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

purge_data = set(o.data for o in context.selected_objects if o.data)
bpy.data.batch_remove(context.selected_objects)
bpy.data.batch_remove([o for o in purge_data if not o.users])
```

To remove only lattices,  and their data if orphan, from selected objects.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context


lattice_obs = [o for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'LATTICE']
purge_data = set(o.data for o in lattice_obs)
bpy.data.batch_remove(lattice_obs)
bpy.data.batch_remove([o for o in purge_data if not o.users])
```

There may be a tricky way to do above with one call and one list.

Similar to  question code, if optimized to only loop the meshes after removing the objects.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

for obj in context.selected_objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
    
for block in bpy.data.meshes:
    if not block.users:
        bpy.data.meshes.remove(block)
```

Comment: Second block code is what I needed. It delete all selected objects as I asked, but can I concretize to delete for example only Lattices objects and purge it data after

Comment: Isn't that the behaviour of  the  batch delete example above, if a lattice is in selected objects it is removed. If it's data is left an orphan it is also removed.  To filter selection to only lattices  `[o for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'LATTICE']`

Comment: sorry for the wrong explanation. So I have selected objects and I need to delete only Lattice and its data. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Thank you!

Comment: Edited example in answer. Changed purge data to set (only one instance of each element) although it appears it doesn't fail with duplicates anyway.